# Background of the Viśvasara Tantra

Tags: mantras, tantra, guru, resource

What is the origin of the Viśvasara Tantra? Does anyone know, when about it was written? It is given as the source for the Guru stotram, but I have not been able to find out more, except that all websites copy from one another.

Comment: Viswasara Tantram is now lost. Only parts of it, which are quoted in other texts, are available at present.

Comment: @Rickross, is durga astottara shata stotam is written there ? I found a doc, wanted ur inputs.

Comment: Various Durga Astottara are found in various scriptures .. in the doc you found does it mention that the stotra is from Viswasra Tantram? @SpiritualAspirant

Comment: This one @Rickross: https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/durga108.html

Comment: Yes it's from Viswasara Tantram as is mentioned at the end of the document .. it is however impossible to verify the claim because the Viswasara Tantram as a scripture is not available now. @SpiritualAspirant

Comment: Thanks @Rickross.

Comment: You can read Manu Smriti  from here  https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi

Comment: @Rickross , can you try to answer this ? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/58246/source-of-durga-dwatrimsha-namavali-stotram

Comment: I have seen that question and upvoted it too but IMO its difficult to answer such questions unless it is clearly mentioned in the stotras themselves as to from which scripture they are taken @SpiritualAspirant But still I will look to find an answer.