# Source of Durga Dwatrimsha Namavali Stotram

Tags: durga, nama-japa

I came across 32 names Stotram of Devi Durga. Here is the [reference](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/durgaa32.html).

Can anyone share the scripture reference? Is it present in Devi Bhagavatam ?

Comment: As i check the whole Devi Bhagavata and all the Puranas, there are no mention of Durga Dwatrimsha Namavali Stotra. Maybe, the Upa Puranas mention it.

Comment: thank for inputs.

Comment: I didn't know about the Tripurarahasya reference mentioned above.
But these 32 names are present in Durga Sapsasati from Geeta Press.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Durgādvātriṃśatnāmāvalī* occurs in the 46th chapter of *Māhātmyakhaṇḍa* of *Tripurārahasya*.

> अथापि त्वां सुपृच्छामो जगद्रक्षणहेतवे । विपन्नं त्वं कथं शीघ्रं प्रसन्ना रक्षसीश्वरी ।। एतन्नो ब्रुहि देवेशि रहस्यमपि सर्वथा । प्रार्थितैवं सुरगणैः प्राह दुर्गा दयान्विता ।। देवाः शृणुध्वमेतत्तु गोप्यमत्यन्तदुर्लभं । द्वात्रिंशन्नाममाला मे सर्वापत्प्रविनाशनी ।।
>
> Translation : 'O *Iśvarī* ! Now we ask you for the sake of protecting the world - How can you be quickly propitiated in order to protect the distressed ? Please do tell us even if it happens to be highly secretive.' Thus on being asked by the *deva*s, *Bhagavatī Durgā* endowed with kindness said, 'O *deva*s ! Hear my very secret & esoteric 32 names that destroys all calamities.' [*Tripurārahasya*:*Māhātmyakhaṇḍa*:46:89-91]

The 7 verses you mentioned occur as verses 93 to 100 which follow the section cited above as given [here](https://archive.org/details/99.tripurarahasyamahatmyakhandahinditranslationvoligurmandalseries28/page/n515/mode/2up)

Comment: Could you also answer these questions https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/58752/any-modern-day-purva-mimansakas https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/58814/does-narasimha-kavacham-require-upanayanam

Comment: I have Tripura Rahashya. It has 22 chapters. I guess, Tripura Rahashya Mahatmyakhanda is a different book. Can you please add a link?

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay I think that you might have the Charya Khanda or the Jnana Khanda from Tripurarahasya masquerading as the entire book. The link to the Mahatmya Khanda with Sanskrit text & Hindi translation  is provided in the main answer.

Comment: I mean English translation?

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay Unfortunately I haven't come across any English translation of the Mahatmya Khanda.