# Any modern day purva mimansakas?

Tags: vedic-rituals, purva-mimamsa, shad-darshana

Most current hindus are vedantins
Is purva mimansa an extinct school or do believers still exist?

Comment: As a darśana & paramparā, Pūrva Mīmāṁsā doesn't survive anymore afaik, however most Vedāntins and those of Vaidika śākhās usually do study Pūrva Mīmāṁsā and employ its techniques in interpretation, etc.. In fact, Advaita Vedānta follows Bhāṭṭa Mīmāṁsā on many issues such as pramāṇas, etc.