# Family tree of Ravana

Tags: ramayana, ravana

Is any family tree of Ravana available? Are there children of Ravana or is there a family tree for his sister's family?

Answer (score 2):

Here would be detailed an expansive lineage of Rāvaṇa's kula, as much as I could find in śāstras and piece together. Usually, in most of the lists available in popular media, the focus is on patrilineal lineage of Rāvaṇa and not on his matrilineal lineage. But among rākṣasas, as is seen in Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa, matrilineal lineage did play a pretty important role too, and so that would be covered here too.

Abbreviation - UK (Uttarakāṇḍa of Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa) ; YK (Yuddhakāṇḍa of the same) ; SK (Sundarakāṇḍa of the same) ; AK (Araṇyakāṇḍa of the same)

Vaivasvata Manu → Diṣṭa → Nābhāga → Bhalandana → Vatsaprīti → Prāṁśu → Pramati → Khanitra → Cākṣuṣa → Viviṁśati → Rambha → Khaninetra → Karandhama → Avīkṣita → Marutta  → Dama → Rājyavardhana → Sudhṛti → Nara → Kevala → Bandhumān → Vegavān → Bandhu → Tṛṇabindu
(Bhāgavata Purāṇa 9.2.23-31)- Tṛṇabindu had vivāha with Alambuṣā, an apsarā. They birthed several sons and a daughter named Iḍaviḍā.

The first rākṣasas were created by Brahmā (Prajāpati) himself. Among those rākṣasas, there were two brothers - Heti and Praheti. Heti fathered a son named Vidyutkeśa, with his wife Bhayā (sister of Kāla). Vidyutkeśa had vivāha with Sālakaṭañkaṭā (daughter of Sandhyā) and fathered Sukeśa (UK 4.16-31). Sukeśa had vivāha with Devavatī (daughter of Grāmaṇī, a gandharva) and fathered three sons with her - Mālyavān, Sumālī, & Mālī (UK 5.1-6). These three brothers had vivāha with Sundarī, Ketumatī, and Vasudā respectively, who were the daughters of Narmadā, a gandharvī. Sundarī bore 7 sons - Vajramuṣṭi, Virūpākṣa, Durmukha, Suptaghna, Yajñakopa, Matta, Unmatta, and a daughter named Analā. Ketumatī bore 10 sons - Prahasta, Akampana, Vikaṭa, Kālakārmuka, Dhūmrākṣa, Daṇḍa, Supārśva, Saṁhrādi, Praghasa, Bhāsakarṇa, and 4 daughters- Rākā, Puṣpotkaṭā, Kaikasī, & Kumbhīnasī I. Vasudā bore 4 sons- Anala, Anila, Hara, & Saṁpāti (UK 5.31-45). Analā (daughter of Mālyavān) had vivāha with Viśvavāsu (UK 61.16) and together bore a daughter named Kumbhīnasī II, second-cousin sister of Rāvaṇa (UK 25.222-24). So, Kumbhīnasī I was Rāvaṇa's maternal aunt (Kaikasī's sibling), while Kumbhīnasī II was Rāvaṇa's cousin sister (from his maternal lineage).  The asura Madhu was the eldest son of Lolā, a daitya i.e. descendant of Diti (UK 61.3) and he had a son named Lavaṇa with his wife Kumbhīnasī II (UK 61.16-17).

Brahmā (Prajāpati) had a son named Pulastya, who was a brahmarṣi. He had vivāha with Iḍaviḍā (daughter of Tṛṇabindu), and fathered a son named Viśravā with her (UK 2.4-28). Viśravā had vivāha with Devavarṇinī (daughter of Ṛṣi Bharadvāja) and fathered a son named Vaiśravaṇa (Kubera) with her (UK 3.3-8). Viśravā fathered four children (rākṣasas) with Kaikasī (daughter of Sumālī) - Daśagrīva (Rāvaṇa), Kumbhakarṇa, daughter Śūrpaṇakhā, & Vibhīṣaṇa (UK 9.19-35). Kumbhakarṇa is mentioned as having two brothers (half-brothers, as per the commentaries Amṛtakataka & Tilaka) - Mahodara and Mahāpārśva (YK 68.8). Rāvaṇa is mentioned as having two other half/cousin brothers viz. Khara & Duṣaṇa (AK 17.20-23), but their parentage isn't mentioned in Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa.

Śūrpaṇakhā had vivāha with the dānavarāja Vidyujjihva, son of Kālaka (UK 12.2).  Asura Maya (son of Diti) had vivāha with Hemā, an apsarā. Hemā bore (to Maya) two sons - Māyāvī & Dundubhi, and a daughter named Mandodarī. Rāvaṇa had vivāha with Mandodarī (UK 12.5-20) and fathered Meghanāda aka Indrajit with her (UK 12.28-29). Rāvaṇa fathered Atikāya with his wife Dhānyamālinī (YK 71.30). Rāvaṇa is mentioned as having other sons - Triśirā, Devāntaka, Narāntaka (YK 68.7), and Akṣa (SK 47-48). So, Rāvaṇa is mentioned as having 6 sons, in Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa. There was another Triśirā, who served as a senāpati under Khara (and had died earlier at hands of Rāma - AK 27), but he wasn't Rāvaṇa's son.

There is a popular online myth that Prahasta was the son of Rāvaṇa, but as aforementioned, in the Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa, Prahasta is the maternal uncle of Rāvaṇa, being the sibling of Rāvaṇa's mother Kaikasī.

Kumbhakarṇa had vivāha with Vajrajvālā, daughter of Vairocana and Vibhīṣaṇa had vivāha with Saramā, daughter of gandharvarāja Śailūṣa (UK 12.23-26). Kumbha & Nikumbha were the sons of Kumbhakarṇa (YK 75.45-46).

There are some other slightly different accounts (different from the one in Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa) on Viśravā's wives and children (as well as grand-daughters of Sukeśu), I would be sharing five of them, from Padma Purāṇa, Agni Purāṇa, Vāyu Purāṇa, Rāmopākhyāna (of Mahābhārata), & Liṅga Purāṇa.

As per Agni Purāṇa ([11.2-4](https://archive.org/details/AgniPuranaChowkhambaSurbharati/page/n31/mode/2up?view=theater)), Viśravā had 2 wives - Puṣpotkaṭā & Kaikasī. Kubera was the son of Puṣpotkaṭā. Rāvaṇa, Kumbhakarṇa, Vibhīṣaṇa, & Śūrpaṇakhā, were the children of Kaikasī. As per Padma Purāṇa ([5.6.17-20](https://archive.org/details/sri-padma-maha-purana-part-5-patal-khanda-printed-khemraj-1895-jangamwadi-math-collection/page/n13/mode/2up?view=theater)), Viśravā had 2 wives - Mandākinī & Kaikasī. The former bore Kubera and the latter bore Rāvaṇa, Kumbhakarṇa, & Śūrpaṇakhā. As per Vāyu Purāṇa ([70.33-50](https://archive.org/details/wg1194/page/n667/mode/2up?view=theater)), Viśravā had vivāha with four wives - Devavarṇinī (daughter of Bṛhaspati), Puṣpotkaṭā (daughter of Mālyavān), Vākā (daughter of Mālyavān), and Kaikasī (daughter of Mālī). Devavarṇinī bore Vaiśravaṇa (Kubera). Kaikasī bore Rāvaṇa, Kumbhakarṇa, Vibhīṣaṇa, & Śūrpaṇakhā. Puṣpotkaṭā bore Mahodara, Prahasta, Mahāpāṁśu, Khara, and Kumbhīnasī I. Vākā bore Triśirā, Duṣaṇa, Vidyujjihva, and Asalikā (daughter).

As per Vana Parva (274.12-14 ; 275.1), Pulastya fathered Vaiśravaṇa (Kubera) with his wife named Gau. Later (275.5-8), Pulastya had another son Viśravā (who was his very krodharūpa). Then Viśravā fathered Rāvaṇa & Kumbhakarṇa (with Puṣpotkaṭā), Vibhīṣaṇa (with Mālinī), and Khara & Śūrpaṇakhā (with Rākā).

As per Liṅga Purāṇa ([1.63.58-65](https://archive.org/details/DCoB_linga-mahapuran-of-veda-vyas-with-illustration-gita-press/page/n275/mode/2up?view=theater)), Viśravā had four wives - Devavarṇinī (daughter of Bṛhaspati), Puṣpotkaṭā & Balākā (daughters of Mālyavān), and Kaikasī (daughter of Mālī). Devavarṇinī bore Vaiśravaṇa (Kubera). Puṣpotkaṭā bore Mahodara, Prahasta, Mahāpārśva, Khara, & Kumbhīnasī I. Balākā bore Triśirā, Dūṣaṇa, Viddyujjihva, & Mālikā (daughter).
In the lists of Vāyu Purāṇa & Liṅga Purāṇa, we see Triśirā & Dūṣaṇa being the sons of Vākā/Balākā and Khara being the son of Puṣpotkaṭā. This Triśirā is Rāvaṇa's half-brother, who died in the battle early on in AK, as aforementioned, unlike Rāvaṇa's son named Triśirā, who died much later in YK.

*The numbering of ślokas from Mahābhārata & Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa, follow Gītā press versions.*

Comment: Hello, could you answer these questions https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/58814/does-narasimha-kavacham-require-upanayanam https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/58752/any-modern-day-purva-mimansakas

Answer (score 0):

Ravana's lineage traces back to Sage Pulastya, who was a mind-born son of Lord Brahma. Pulastya and his wife Havirbhu had two famous sons, Vishrava and Agastya, both of whom became great sages. Ravana was born from Vishrava and his wife Kaikasi.

Ravana had seven sons:

1. Indrajit
2. Prahast
3. Atikay
4. Akshya Kumar
5. Devantak
6. Narantak
7. Trishir

All of Ravana's sons, along with Ravana himself, died in the Battle of Lanka.
Following is the family tree of Ravana:

```
Lord Brahma
 |
 |--- Sage Pulastya
          |
          |--- Vishrava
                 |
                 |--- Ravana
                          |--- Indrajit
                          |--- Prahast
                          |--- Atikay
                          |--- Akshya Kumar
                          |--- Devantak
                          |--- Narantak
                          |--- Trishir
          |--- Agastya
```

Refrences:

- [Wiki Pulastya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulastya)
- [Wiki Ravana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravana)

Comment: Please don't use wiki as a source of reference, when answering such questions. It would be better to support your answer with śāstras.