# Does narasimha kavacham require upanayanam?

Tags: puranas, narasimha, upanayanam, kavacha

Is it true that some stotras from puranas require upanayana?

Comment: I have read that Shudras (or uninitiates) can read Stotras and Kavachas without Swaha, Om etc. in them. Need to find the exact verses.

Comment: So nrisimha kavacam can't be chanted cuz it has swaha? @Rickross

Comment: Based on what I have heard (not aware of śāstrīya support), Narasiṁha kavacam does require dīkṣā like kavacams in general. I don't think it requires Vedādhikāra because it doesn't seem to contain Vaidika mantras, and it's found in Brahmāṇḍa Purāṇa. Most stotras from Purāṇas don't require Vedādhikāra, but some may require dīkṣā. For e.g. Lalitā sahasranāma, for which dīkṣā in Śrīvidyā is required.

Comment: Thank you; is the pauranik nrisimha kavacham different from the one in brihat tantrasara? The stotras and kavachams in brihat tantrasara need diksha too?

Comment: Stotras can be recited by everyone with certain modifications .. for example where there is swaha the uninitiates have to chant Hrim .. where there is Om they have to chant Namaha. The Brihat tantra sara stotras are from some scriptures or the other so general rules of stotra recital apply on them too @amit