# What is the source of Durga Chalisa.?

Tags: reference-request, durga, shakti, shaktism, shakta

I just saw Durga Chalisa for the first time in my life. I never heard about it before. I am a practising Shakta. But still, I never heard about it. Here is a [link](https://archive.org/details/durga-chalisa/page/n1/mode/1up?view=theater). It is in Hindi. What is the source of Durga Chalisa.?

I know that Hanuman Chalisa is part of Tulisidasa's rendition of Ramayana. But, what about Durga Chalisa.? Part of which scripture.?

Comment: Chslisas appear to be local paens constituting religious literature in vernacular language prevalent in the Hindi belt, similar to panchalis in Bengal. Like panchalis, anybody with a good command over language can write these chalisas. The market is full of chalisas composed by unknown authors praising various deities. Tulasidasa specifically composed the Hanumanachalisa in order to tap it's appeal, knowing very well that religious discourse given through vernacular literature will trickledown to the masses more efficiently than Sanskrit scriptures.

Comment: This is similar to how Lochanadasa composed the Chaitanyamangala on the biography of Chaitanya Mahaprabhu in order to tap the market of mangalakavyas in Bengal.

Comment: @অনু Panchali. Now, I understood.

Comment: @অনু, can you try to answer this as well ? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/58246/source-of-durga-dwatrimsha-namavali-stotram

Comment: Among chalisas, Hanuman chalisa is seen as very strong almost like a powerful mantra which protects you.